# Mongoid access nested attributes with attributes.values_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Given the following document (snippet):

```
{
    udid: "0E321DD8-1983-4502-B214-97D6FB046746",   
    person: {
        "firstname": "Jacob",
        "lastname": "Prince"
    }
}
```

I'n my console I can basically do:

```
mycollection.first.attributes.values_at("udid", "person")
```

This returns the *person* as a **hash**.

Now I want a single field. But these doesn't work (person.firstname):

```
mycollection.first.attributes.values_at("udid", "person.firstname")
mycollection.first.attributes.values_at("udid", "person[:firstname]")
mycollection.first.attributes.values_at("udid", "person['firstname']")
```

How how do you access the person child-document?

I'm in the need to have *users* select which fieds they want to export. I was thinking along the lines of doing something like this:

```
class Foo
    include Mongoid::Document 

    # fields definitions
    embeds_one :person # two fields: firstname, lastname

    def to_csv *columns
       attributes.values_at *columns
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Whats a (the most) efficient way to select specific fields?

If you already know the fields and its nested keys, using Ruby v2.3+ you can utilise the [dig()](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) built-in method. For example:

```
document = collection.find({},{'projection' => {'uid' => 1, "person.firstname" => 1 }}).first
result = [document.dig("uid"), document.dig("person", "firstname")]
puts result.inspect
```

Alternatively, depending on your application use case you could also utilise [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), especially [$project operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) 
For example:

```
document = collection.aggregate([{"$project"=>{ :uid=>"$uid", :person_firstname=>"$person.firstname"}}]).first
puts document.values_at("uid", "person_firstname").inspect
```

Note that the projection above renames the nested `person.firstname` into a flatten field called `person_firstname`.

See also [MongoDB Ruby Driver: Aggregation Tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-aggregation/)